# Wordpress + Contact Form 7 + Contact Form 7 Datepicker -Custom validation no custom error message

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have created a form with CF7 and I inserted two date fields (with the CF7 datepicker plugin). The two fields are [date* date-641 date-format:mm/dd/yy], [date* date-820 date-format:mm/dd/yy]. The form is a booking form so I have to make some controls about the dates. date-641 is "CHECKIN" date and date-820 is "CHECKOUT"

I have created this:

```
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_date*','custom_date_confirmation_validation_filter', 10, 2 );

function custom_date_confirmation_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {

$tag = new WPCF7_Shortcode( $tag );
$date1 = $_POST['date-641'];
$date2 = $_POST['date-820'];
$error_msg = 'Invalid date';
if ($date2 < $date1){
$result->invalidate( 'date-820', $error_msg); //I used $tag instead of 'date-820' with the same results

 }

 return $result;  
}
```

The control works fine but the error message I get is not the one I set in $error_msg, it is the generic "One or more fields have an error. Please check and try again." What am I doing wrong?